# JNI Warnig expected return type 'L' calling LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates

Tags: android, java-native-interface, android-ndk

I am using Necessitas (QT in Android). Basically, using the Android NDK an android activity calls a QT application (.so).

I am working on some bindings for the GPS. I think I am getting there, however I getting a JNI WARNING (**JNI Warning expected return type 'L'**) when I call the method requestLocationUpdates(String, Long, Float, LocationListener).

Here is some of the code:

```java
midGetSystemService = currEnv->GetMethodID(actClass,"getSystemService","(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;");

jSystemServiceObj = currEnv->CallObjectMethod(currAct,midGetSystemService,StringArg);

midRequestLocationUpdates = currEnv->GetMethodID(locManClass,"requestLocationUpdates","(Ljava/lang/String;JFLandroid/location/LocationListener;)V");


midConstListener = currEnv->GetMethodID(listenerClass, "<init>", "()V");
jListenerObj = currEnv->NewObject(listenerClass, midConstListener);


currEnv->CallObjectMethod(jSystemServiceObj,midRequestLocationUpdates,StringArg,(jlong)1000,(jfloat)10,jListenerObj);  --->Here is the warning
```

Any idea why?

Comment: Hi,

This happens because I need to call CallVoidMethod instead of CallObjectMethod.

Sorry for the silly question.....I am getting tired :-(

Carlos.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are calling a method that returns "void":

```
midConstListener = currEnv->GetMethodID(listenerClass, "<init>", "()V");
```

using a JNI call that expects in return a JNI object:

```
// BAD
currEnv->CallObjectMethod(jSystemServiceObj,midRequestLocationUpdates,StringArg,(jlong)1000,(jfloat)10,jListenerObj);
```

You should instead use the JNI call that expects void in return:

```
// GOOD
currEnv->CallVoidMethod(jSystemServiceObj,midRequestLocationUpdates,StringArg,(jlong)1000,(jfloat)10,jListenerObj);
```

Comment: In my case `activity.callMethod<void>("setRequestedOrientation", "(I)V", 0);`